# Using data-fields to store JSON?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, html

Here is my code, basically I have a generic open_modal function i wrote in jQuery and I want to use `data-fields` to pass the `{'json':'data'}`.

So heres my code.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fFCZc/1/)

**HTML**

```
    <a href="#" class="send_request" data-dataset="{'test':1}" data-url="/test.html">Data load!</a>
<div id="area"></div>
```

​**jQuery**

```
   $("body").delegate(".send_request", 'click', function(e) {

        var $this = $(this);
        var $modal_data = $("#area");
        var $url = $this.attr('data-url');
        var $dataset = JSON.stringify($this.data('dataset'));

        alert($dataset);

        $("#area").load($url,$dataset);
        return false;
    });​
```

Basically its not working, the data isn't being passed. Does the data-field data need to be parsed first somehow?

Comment: You forgot the question.

Comment: Updated, do I get a badge for being an idiot?

Comment: Does `./test.html` expect data to be passed via a GET or POST request?

Comment: Just receiving a querystring.

Answer (score 2):

The object in data-dataset is already a JSON object at the point of retrieval and also you need double quotes in specifying JSON attribute names. doing the following should work:

In your html snippet:

`data-dataset="{'test':1}"` to `data-dataset='{"test":1}'`

In your JS code

`var $dataset = JSON.stringify($this.data('dataset'));`

to  `var $dataset = $this.data('dataset');`

Here's a modified version of your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/C3Cbe/2/.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet retrieves both pieces of data just fine but it later feeds an AJAX call with a literal JSON string (not a JavaScript object):

```
$("#area").load($url,$dataset);
```

This ends up in a GET request like this:

```
/test.html?%22{%27test%27:1}%22
```

... which is probably not what you intended.

**Update:**

My recommendations are:

1. Fix your JSON string, which is currently invalid (you are using single quotes for property names)
2. Use `JSON.parse()` or jQuery's equivalent.

Comment: @chris, in what format does `test.html` expect to receive the data?

Answer (score 0):

The attribute value is already stringified, you would have to run it through `JSON.parse` to convert it from a JSON text to a JavaScript object.

It isn't possible to tell if you should convert it to a JavaScript object or not, as we don't know what the server at the other end of the request expects. You certainly shouldn't be `stringify`ing it.

Your example, however, is invalid JSON. JSON strings must be quoted with `"` characters. `'` is not acceptable.